# Imagick number of supported formats is zero: phpinfo(), Apache/2.4.25(Win 64) PHP/7.1.2; Windows 10

Tags: php, apache, imagick

I know this is one of those questions that is as old as Internet and I have looked everywhere and followed the steps that majority of previous answers point to, but still number of supported formats by imagick in `phpinfo()` is zero for Windows 10.

Let me list the steps that I carried out:

1. Install Apache 2.4.25-win64-vc14 built by Apache lounge.
2. Install PHP 7.1 thread safe version VC14 x64

So far so good. I see everything I want to see sans Imagick. I think my problem starts from below:

3. Install `ImageMagick-7.0.5-2Q16-X64-dll.exe` from
   "[Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)"
4. Copy everything from "`C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16\coders`" to "`C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16`"
5. Copy everything from "`C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16\filters`" to "`C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16`"
6. Copy everything from "`C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16\coders`" to "`C:\Apache24\bin`"
7. Copy everything from "`C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16\filters`" to "`C:\Apache24\bin`"
8. Set the environment variable `MAGICK_HOME` to "`C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16`"
9. Download PHP 7.1 Thread Safe x64 version of Imagick dll for php extension from `https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.4.3/windows`
10. Copy `php_imagick.dll` from the package to "`C:\php7\ext`", the PHP folder
11. Copy all the "`CORE_RL_xxx.dll`" to "`C:\Apache24\bin`", the Apache bin folder
12. Change the `php.ini` in the PHP folder to include "`extension = php_imagick.dll`". Save the file.
13. Restart Apache, no luck.
14. Restart PC and then start Apache, no luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: I do not know why you are doing steps 4 - 8. A standard Imagemagick install should do all that as long as you remember to click the "add to environmental path" box. I am running Imagemagick on Windows 10 and a localhost without a problem. I do not use Imagick as I do not like it and as you have found it is a pain to install; Imagemagick with exec() is my preferred method. If you want to use it on your server I assume it is working there and you could build the rest of your site on a localhost and write the Imagick part on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Please download the latest stable versions of *both* ImageMagick and Imagick from:

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/

Installing versions that are downloaded from different places isn't likely to work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download `php_imagick` from
   http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.4.3/php_imagick-3.4.3-7.0-ts-vc14-x64.zip - for `PHP 7.0` or http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.4.3/php_imagick-3.4.3-7.1-ts-vc14-x64.zip - for `PHP 7.1`
2. Download `imagemagick` from: http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-vc14-x64.zip instead of `ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16`
3. Extract from `php_imagick-3.4.3-7.0-ts-vc14-x64.zip` to the `ext` directory only the `php_imagick.dll` file of your PHP installation
4. Extract `ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-vc14-x64.zip` to the directory `c:\ImageMagick`- for example
5. add to environmental PATH to `c:\ImageMagick\bin`. Attention: `bin`!!!
6. Add this line to your `php.ini` file: `extension=php_imagick.dll`
7. Restart Apache

Result `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`:
[image]